# How to map Enum type in mybatis using typeHandler on insert

Tags: java, mysql, enums, mybatis, typehandler

I have strugled with enum for a while now but it will not go my way. 
Is there anyone that can give me hint?
I am trying to use Enum type in MySql and I also use an Enum class in my code.

As the code is now It will insert MONDAY but it will also try to insert MONDAY on workdayID... I do not get the workdayID.
I belive I have to handle the DAY_TYPE in som way ... define a typeHandler maybe??
but I tried that and it would not work, or its becouse I can not do it correct?

I also tried the org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler but with no success, like this

```
    #{DAY_TYPE,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler}
```

DAY_TYPE.java

```
    package tut.model;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    public enum DAY_TYPE implements Serializable{
        MONDAY(1),TUESDAY(2),WEDNESDAY(3),THURSDAY(4),FRIDAY(5),SATURDAY(6),SUNDAY(7);
        private int id; private int workdayID;

        private DAY_TYPE(int id) { this.id = id; }

        public int getId() { return id;    }
        public void setId(int id) {  this.id = id;    }

        public int getWorkdayID() { return workdayID;    }
        public void setWorkdayID(int workdayID) {this.workdayID = workdayID;}
    }
```

DAY_TYPE_Mapper.xml

```
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="DAY_TYPE" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="iddaytaype">
        INSERT INTO daytaype (DAY_TYPE, workdayID)
        VALUES (#{DAY_TYPE},#{workdayID})
        <selectKey keyProperty="iddaytaype" resultType="long" order="AFTER">
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        </selectKey>
    </insert>

<!-- <insert id="insert" parameterMap="insert-params" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="iddaytaype"> -->
    <parameterMap id="insert-params"   type="DAY_TYPE">
        <parameter property="DAY_TYPE" javaType="DAY_TYPE" typeHandler="mappings.XenumTypeHandler"  />
        <parameter property="workdayID" javaType="int" />
    </parameterMap>
```

My database table

```
    CREATE TABLE `daytaype` (
      `iddaytaype` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DAY_TYPE` enum('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY') NOT NULL,
      `workdayID` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`iddaytaype`),
      KEY `fk_workDayID_idWorkDay` (`workdayID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Maybe one can not use enum as a parameterType? 
Like this  `parameterType="DAY_TYPE"`

Comment: Ok ,anyone?
 At least tell me if  I am  impatient or haven't done my homework or there is something else missing, and yes I know that some people say one normally do not store enum value in the code and in the database just the id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219253/mybatis-enum-usage

Comment: Thanks @jalopaba I see your point, it is not possible to have an extra property in the enum class. I will wrap it inside a regular class instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workday exists as this

```
    public class Workday implements Serializable{
        private long idWorkDay;
        private Date start;
        private Date end;
        private List<Workbreak> workBreaks;
        private DAY_TYPE DAY_TYPE;
        private long workweekID;
        getter setter....
```

The correct solution is of course to add enum in the workday table ... and it will reduse database seize a lot I belive.

```
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="workday" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="idWorkDay">
      INSERT INTO workday 
        ( start , end , workweekID , DAY_TYPE )
      VALUES (
        #{start},
        #{end},
        #{workweekID},
        #{DAY_TYPE, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler}
      )
        <selectKey keyProperty="idWorkDay" resultType="long" order="AFTER">
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        </selectKey>
    </insert>
```

And now delete daytaype table
And add enum directly in workday table instead.

```
    CREATE TABLE `workday` (
      `idworkday` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `start` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
      `end` time DEFAULT '17:00:00',
      `workweekID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DAY_TYPE` enum('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY') DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idworkday`),
      KEY `fk_workweek_workweekID` (`workweekID`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_workweek_workweekID` FOREIGN KEY (`workweekID`) REFERENCES `workweek` (`idworkweek`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=139 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

override getter setter. my  like this:

```
@Column(name = "type")
private MailType type;

public String getType(){
    return type.name();
}
public void setType(String type){
    this.type = MailType.valueOf(type);
}
public MailType getTypeEnum(){
    return type;
}
public void setTypeEnum(MailType type){
    this.type = type;
}
```

Comment: This works well if you're okay with renaming your enum setter

Answer (score 0):

DAY_TYPE in your case contains a member id.
Now if you store your ENUM as id in the database you can always use a CustomEnumTypeHandler which can handle the DAY_TYPE for you even if you don't have your Enum synced with your database.