# Specifying a type handler for an annotated MyBatis insert

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

I am trying to create an annotated insert statement using MyBatis where the type handler is specified in an annotation.

For example, in a select query we can specify the typehandler like this:

```
@Results({
        @Result(column = "strings", property = "strings", typeHandler = StringArrayTypeHandler.class)
})
@Select("SELECT * FROM ${name} ORDER BY id ASC;")
List<StringObject> getStringObjects(@Param("name") String name);
```

However, the same does not appear possible for an insert query as the `@Results` annotation is only for `@Select` queries.

Currently, my work around is to specify the type handler as part of the query string like this:

```
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true)
@Insert({"INSERT INTO ${name} (text, value, strings) VALUES (#{obj.text}, #{obj.value}, #{obj.strings, typeHandler=com.mypackage.typehandler.StringArrayTypeHandler});"})
void insertStringObject(@Param("obj") SenticConcept concept, @Param("name") String version);
```

My question is, can we specify the type handler class in an annotation rather than being part of the query string?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.

The result mapping uses column names as keys because column values in the result set can be identified using column name, that is mybatis can get the value of some column by its name. So it can use a mapping configuration (for example `typeHandler`) to process the value in that column.

The input parameters to the query in JDBC are identifiable only by the index of the parameter. In principle it is possible to implement an annotation that would specify the `typeHandler` based on the index of the parameter, but this is error prone because a change in the query may cause the change in the parameter indices (that's probably the reason it is not done in mybatis).

Comment: this can be done by specifying typehandler in insert sql : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137648/1145750

Comment: @GaryGauh can you elaborate how to specify typhandler **in annotation** as OP asks, please? The answer you referred to allows to do this in the body of the query and this is known to and mentioned in the question but is not what this is question about.